# FOSJsRoutingBundle not working

Tags: ajax, symfony

I am trying to get result from a drop-down using ajax and symfony; I did all the settings as it is which is mentioned in the documentation provided. But I am getting 
**POST http://localhost/docCMS/web/app_dev.php/getclientaddress/13 500 Internal Server Error**

### DefaultController.php

```
/**
* @Route("/getclientaddress/{id}", name="get_client_address", options={"expose"=true})
* @Template("SuntecMarcusAssignmentBundle:Default:getclientaddress.html.twig")
*/
public function getclientaddressAction($getclientaddress){
    $client = $this->get_client_details($id);
```

### routing.yml

```
fos_js_routing:
resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

suntec_marcus_getclientaddress:
pattern:   /getclientaddress/{param}
defaults: { _controller: SuntecMarcusAssignmentBundle:Default:getclientaddress }
options:
    expose: true
```

### ajax

```
$(document).on('change', '#client',  function (){
    var client_id = $(this).val();
    var getTeamsUrl = Routing.generate('get_client_address',{ id: client_id });
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : getTeamsUrl,
        success : function(response){
            alert(response);
            },error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you added fos routing js files into layout?

Comment: And why do you think it's FOSRouting what's not working? It's 500 error. What is says?